# Do reactive programming and pi-calculus have things in common?

Tags: computer-science, reactive-programming

Do [reactive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming)  and [pi-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_calculus) have things in common?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes.  Technically the Pi-calculus could probably encode something like higher-order reactive programming (as you can dynamically create and pass around channels as first-class values).

At a superficial level, both attempt to describe a system in terms of events, rather than states.  This is an important distinction that gives rise to the field of 'event-based systems'.  The Pi-calculus is extremely general, and it's quite likely that anything you could construct in a reactive programming setting would have a reasonably natural encoding as pi-calculus terms.